# blender 2.8 shader editor normal map missing

Tags: normal-map

When I go to the shader editor and search for "normal map" there are no results. Where would I add a normal map to the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where were you searching from? Were you using the regular F3 search function or were you using the Shift+A function inside the Shader Editor? The add node function (which is Shift+A) comes with its own searching feature which searches through all of the different nodes, which will include Normal Map.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the search doesn't work but I found the Normal Map under Add - Vector - Normal Map.